# What are the endpoints of Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, istio

I've created an "Istio-enabled" Kubernetes cluster, and my containers, by default, "[are unable to access URLs outside of the cluster](https://archive.istio.io/v1.0/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/)" (Istio v1.0.2). This is fine and matches my security requirements:

> By default, Istio-enabled services are unable to access URLs outside
>   of the cluster because the pod uses iptables to transparently redirect
>   all outbound traffic to the sidecar proxy...

Now I'm trying to create an [Istio Service Entry](https://archive.istio.io/v1.0/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#service-entries) to **allow my containers to requests my s3 buckets** that are outside the Istio service mesh.

As far I know, Amazon S3 does not have a specific "host" or a well-defined range of IP addresses. How can I do this? What protocol do I need to use?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: enable-access-to-s3-buckets
spec:
  hosts:
  - ????????
  ports:
  - number: ???????
    name: ??????
    protocol: ??????
  resolution: ?????
```

---

*Note: [Istio v1.2](https://istio.io/news/2019/announcing-1.2/#traffic-management) changed the default outbound traffic policy to `ALLOW_ANY`.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking here you can get a list on the terminating points of s3 that might help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Another solution can be to create a s3 endpoint inside the same VPC of your K8S cluster and use that name to restrict the access with private IPs rules. see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html for a detailed documentation on it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Seems reasonable to use the _terminating points_ as `hosts` and _DNS_ as `resolution` in the Service Entry (Or did I misunderstand it?). I'll make some tests and let you know if it solves my problem.

Comment: I've created a ServiceEntry and a VirtualService that matches my bucket name with the endpoint for my region (example [here](https://gist.github.com/eduardobaitello/b7217bee200ca833a8016e1b5b1669ff)). My containers can now use `aws-cli` to make s3 requests. Thanks!

Comment: @EduardoBaitello You may want specify wildcards in the ServiceEntry and VirtualService, e.g.  `*.s3.amazonaws.com` to allow access to any s3 service.

Comment: @VadimEisenberg, thanks for the tip, but I want to make it more restricted as possible, so using _**my-bucket-name**.s3.amazonaws.com_ allow my containers to request only buckets that are explicitly allowed.

Comment: @EduardoBaitello I see, that definitely makes sense.

Comment: @VadimEisenberg in top of that seems like that [Istio 1.0.3](https://istio.io/about/notes/1.0.3/) no longer supports wildcard in ServiceEntry using DNS resolution :)

Comment: @VadimEisenberg thats a really good point ! Thanks for signaling it.

Comment: @EduardoBaitello I do not think you need DNS resolution for the ServiceEntry, since in your case DNS resolution is probably performed by the application itself (you do not have to do it by Istio sidecar proxies).